# Need to get all Stylesheets from a website by URL - JAVA

Tags: java, css, libraries, css-parsing

Hi guys I need for my project a CSS parser. I just look around and I find always the same libraries. But they don't have the implementation for obtaining the CSS file or code from a website. All of them need local files that I don't have because I want to analyze for example Facebook or Twitter etc.

Is there a library for this purpose?

I already found libraries like -> CSSPARSER, SAC

EDIT:

Found a solution for my problem. First of all, I use JSOUP to find out which link belongs to the CSS stylesheet. Then I filter it and save the URL to the CSS file into a string variable. After that, I download this file by the given name and put this file into the CSS parser and now its works.

Comment: [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Comment: and where should i know which file is the css file?